# How can I create an Rc<RefCell<_>> to something that already exists?

Tags: rust

So, in order to teach myself some Rust, I decided to create a simply hybrid datatype that I like, the ChainVec.  It's a doubly linked list of vectors, useful if you need to resize vectors that could grow to vast scales.  It uses linked list logic, but the lookup, search, and iterate characteristics are much faster because they grow O(n/alot).  That's not really the point, though: The problem I ran into would occur in any doubly linked list.

Here's the problem... in C, when I make the new linked list node, I can just set its 'tail' to a pointer to the previous.  I can toss pointers like candy in C, but in Rust, I don't know how to create new pointers yet.  Here is what I tried... (look under fn push_head for the invalid line)

Note: In my implementation, the 'head' node to the chainvec is whichever you choose to point to, so there is no separate struct for the list head/tail.

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

#[allow(dead_code)]
struct ChainVec<T> {
    item: Option<Vec<T>>,
    head: Option<Rc<RefCell<ChainVec<T>>>>,
    tail: Option<Rc<RefCell<ChainVec<T>>>>,
}

impl<T> ChainVec<T> {
    fn new(prealloc: usize) -> Self {
        let vector: Vec<T> = Vec::with_capacity(prealloc);
        Self {
            item: Some(vector),
            head: None,
            tail: None,
        }
    }

    fn new_with_links(
        prealloc: usize,
        head: Option<Rc<RefCell<ChainVec<T>>>>,
        tail: Option<Rc<RefCell<ChainVec<T>>>>,
    ) -> Self {
        let vector: Vec<T> = Vec::with_capacity(prealloc);
        Self {
            item: Some(vector),
            head: head,
            tail: tail,
        }
    }
    fn push_head(&mut self, prealloc: usize) {
        self.head = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(ChainVec::new_with_links(
            prealloc,
            None,
            Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(self))),
        ))));
    }
}

#[allow(unused_variables)]
fn main() {
    let alef: ChainVec<u32> = ChainVec::new(100);
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Obviously I got lost when I tried to create a new pointer in `push_head`. I got:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:36:39
   |
36 |             Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(self))),
   |                          ------------ ^^^^ expected struct `ChainVec`, found `&mut ChainVec<T>`
   |                          |
   |                          arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note:         expected struct `ChainVec<T>`
           found mutable reference `&mut ChainVec<T>`
```

A dereference operator doesn't do anything here... and I'm not sure how to proceed.

How would I create an `Rc<RefCell<_>>` that references a struct that already exists?

Comment: Unrelated to your direct question, but still important: don't use `Rc` in both directions. At least one direction needs `Weak`, otherwise you have a circular reference which leaks memory. Rust does not have a garbage collector.

Comment: Also, if you are implementing a linked list structure, this is almost mandatory: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't.

As soon as you are inside of a function that takes `&self` or `&mut self` as a parameter, the function has no knowledge about the fact that it is wrapped in an `Rc`. So you cannot create a new `Rc` from it.

If you could, how would the existing `Rc`s and the new `Rc` know how long to keep the object alive, and when to delete it?

You can only ever create a new `Rc` from an existing one. That means, if you want to achieve that, you need to take the existing `Rc` as a parameter instead of `&self`.

---

As an excurse on how other libraries deal with this:

[`tokio_util::sync::CancellationToken`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.7.4/src/tokio_util/sync/cancellation_token.rs.html#100) has a similar problem. Its solution is to hide the `Rc` in the `.inner` member, and then when operating on it, it passes the entire `Arc` to the handling method.

You can see this for example on the [`clone()`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.7.4/src/tokio_util/sync/cancellation_token.rs.html#79), which does pretty much exactly what you are trying to do: it runs some code on it and creates a new `Arc`. You can see how it passes the entire `Arc` into the `tree_node::` function; the `tree_node` mod is pretty much like the collection of member functions that operate on the `Arc`.

---

### More details

There is only two ways to create an `Rc` object:

- By transferring ownership of an owned but not yet refcounted object into it. For example, if you have `self` (not `&self`), you can do `Rc::new(self)`, which moves `self` into a new reference counted storage and returns an `Rc` to it.
- From an existing `Rc`: If you halready have an `Rc` object, meaning, the reference counted object already lives in a reference counted storage, you can do `Rc::clone(&other_rc)`, which simply increases the reference count by one and returns a new `Rc` object.

You can **not** create an `Rc` object from `&self` or `&mut self`, because those are references, meaning the object the reference is already stored somewhere else. You cannot create a *new* `Rc` reference counter for a reference, because `Rc` has to *own* the object (makes sense, because it has to destroy the object if all `Rc` references to it are gone, and you can't destroy an object behind a reference). Even if the object referenced by `&self` already lives inside of a reference counted storage, the datatype `&self` has no way of finding that out. You need an actual `Rc` object to create a new `Rc` object.

Here is an example of how this could work. Note that I also made `tail` a `Weak` reference to avoid cyclic references.

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

use std::{
    cell::RefCell,
    fmt::Debug,
    rc::{Rc, Weak},
};

pub struct ChainVecNode<T> {
    item: Vec<T>,
    head: Option<ChainVec<T>>,
    tail: Option<ChainVecWeak<T>>,
}

pub struct ChainVec<T> {
    inner: Rc<RefCell<ChainVecNode<T>>>,
}

pub struct ChainVecWeak<T> {
    inner: Weak<RefCell<ChainVecNode<T>>>,
}

impl<T> ChainVecNode<T> {
    fn push_head(this: &Rc<RefCell<ChainVecNode<T>>>, prealloc: usize) {
        this.borrow_mut().head = Some(ChainVec::new_with_links(
            prealloc,
            None,
            Some(ChainVecWeak {
                inner: Rc::downgrade(this),
            }),
        ))
    }
}

impl<T> ChainVec<T> {
    fn new(prealloc: usize) -> Self {
        Self::new_with_links(prealloc, None, None)
    }

    fn new_with_links(
        prealloc: usize,
        head: Option<ChainVec<T>>,
        tail: Option<ChainVecWeak<T>>,
    ) -> Self {
        let item: Vec<T> = Vec::with_capacity(prealloc);
        Self {
            inner: Rc::new(RefCell::new(ChainVecNode { item, head, tail })),
        }
    }

    fn push_head(&mut self, prealloc: usize) {
        ChainVecNode::push_head(&self.inner, prealloc)
    }
}

impl<T: Debug> Debug for ChainVec<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        writeln!(f, "ChainVec {{")?;
        let mut current = Rc::clone(&self.inner);
        loop {
            let current_ref = current.borrow();
            writeln!(f, "    {:?}", current_ref.item)?;
            let next = if let Some(next) = &current_ref.head {
                Rc::clone(&next.inner)
            } else {
                break;
            };

            drop(current_ref);
            current = next;
        }
        write!(f, "}}")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut chain_vec: ChainVec<u32> = ChainVec::new(100);
    chain_vec
        .inner
        .borrow_mut()
        .item
        .extend_from_slice(&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

    chain_vec.push_head(100);

    println!("{:?}", chain_vec)
}
```

```
ChainVec {
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    []
}
```

Note that I forward the call of `push_head` into `ChainVecNode::push_head`, but pass `self` (here called `this`) as an actual `&Rc` object. This is the trick that is necessary to deal with this problem.

Comment: Alright, I'd admit it, I don't get this answer at all... but I think you successfully answered it and showed me where to look and what to read up on to learn the next stage of this.  I think this is a very good and helpful answer, thank you.  I'll look harder at this Rc::clone thing.  Basically, I need an Rc available to the root node, or I cannot link it.

Comment: Let me try to modify your code, maybe it becomes clearer then

Comment: And if you struggle with these concepts, *definitely* read this: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/ and maybe pick an easier toy problem first, linked lists in Rust are a very advanced topic due to accompanying lifetime problems.

Comment: @AnalogMoose Added example of how your code could be rewritten to deal with this problem. But again, please read the too-many-lists article, this one really explains linked lists in Rust in detail.

Comment: Thank you... you just answered my next three questions.  I'll go work all this out.